# Cannot change Yii2 theme

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, theming

I have installed Yii2 advanced application, and now I'm trying to change frontend theme to [this](http://yii2.themefactory.net/theme/40/interior). I tried to do it using the instructions from the website themefactory, and instructions from the official `Yii2` [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html), but I still can't do it.

I put this theme in a folder `/myyii2folder/frontend/themes` and set the following changes to the file `/myyii2folder/frontend/config/main.php` (I show the entire file):

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'view' => [
            'layout' => '@app/themes/interior/layouts'
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@app/themes/interior',
                'baseUrl' => '@app/themes/interior',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@app/themes/interior',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'params' => $params,
];
```

This is structure of theme:

```
themes
└── interior
    ├── files
    │   ├── main_style.css
    │   └── theme
    │       ├── banner-landing.jpg
    │       ├── banner-short.jpg
    │       ├── banner-splash.jpg
    │       ├── banner-tall.jpg
    │       ├── button_highlight.png
    │       ├── button_large_highlight.png
    │       ├── button_large.png
    │       ├── button.png
    │       ├── facebook-h.png
    │       ├── facebook.png
    │       ├── field.png
    │       ├── header-wrap-bg.png
    │       ├── img.png
    │       ├── linkedin-h.png
    │       ├── linkedin.png
    │       ├── main_style.css
    │       ├── nav-left-bg.png
    │       ├── nav-right-bg.png
    │       ├── rounded.png
    │       ├── rss-h.png
    │       ├── rss.png
    │       ├── searchForm-bg.png
    │       ├── social-grey.png
    │       ├── social-midgrey.png
    │       ├── twitter-h.png
    │       └── twitter.png
    ├── layouts
    │   └── main.php
    └── site
        ├── about.php
        ├── contact.php
        ├── error.php
        ├── index.php
        ├── login.php
        ├── requestPasswordResetToken.php
        ├── resetPassword.php
        └── signup.php
```

Now I see a blank page when loading my site. If I remove `layout` section in `components => view`, I see the default Yii2 theme without any changes.

How I can fix this?

Comment: i think you have to check permissions for that folders

Comment: i think this link is help to you `http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I set 0755 permissions for folders and 0644 for files and now it works!

Comment: Also it is necessary to remove a section `layout` from `components => view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
    'view' => [
        'layout' => '@frontend/themes/interior/layouts'
        'theme' => [
            'basePath' => '@frontend/themes/interior',
            'baseUrl' => '@frontend/themes/interior',
            'pathMap' => [
                '@frontent/views' => '@frontend/themes/interior',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```